# Another python script puking ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I'm using python and the .py script is puking. Here is my output below:

```
reading file 'ConstantVel_Grid1.txt'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "velocity.py", line 199, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "velocity.py", line 79, in main
    (timeInMyrs, moveFileName) = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here is some of the code it is referencing.
Line 199 and context (the last line of the script):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Line 79 and context:

```
allFiles = []

    while True:
        line = inputFile.readline().strip()
        if not line: # no more input left in file
            break

        (timeInMyrs, moveFileName) = line.split()
        allFiles.append((float(timeInMyrs), moveFileName))

    inputFile.close()
```

Here is a sample of the .txt file it is reading, which goes on for about 40 lines:

```
23.0 Grid1_Step0.dat
22.42 Grid1_Step1a.dat
21.84 Grid1_Step1b.dat
21.63 Grid1_Step1c.dat
20.68 Grid1_Step1d.dat
```

The .dat files are also space separated.

Any advice? The many other questions that have been answering this ValueError aren't making much sense for this as I am a noob and knee deep in python for the second time ever. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Add a simple `print line.split()` before the assignment line and see what it prints.

Comment: It might be helpful not only to provie error messages,  but the underlying code,

Comment: Yup, we shouldn't have to be psychic here. The traceback clearly indicates the problem is on line 79 of velocity.py, so it would have been helpful to know what that piece of code looked like (though you have already had hints).

Comment: Thank you all! The underlying code is a million miles long. One of the solutions seems to have helped though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you exactly what the problem is - "too many values to unpack".

When you .split() a string, it splits on whitespace and returns a list of items.

Somewhere you have a line with 3 or more pieces (maybe a filename with a space in it?), so you are effectively trying to

```
timeInMyrs, moveFileName = ["21.63", "my", "file.dat"]
```

and it crashes because you can't fit three values into two variables. To find the problematic line,

```
try:
    timeInMyrs, moveFileName = line.split()
except ValueError:
    print("Couldn't parse line '{}'".format(line.rstrip()))
```

And to solve the problem, either (a) avoid filenames with spaces in them, (b) enclose filenames in quotation-marks and use the 'csv' module to read the input file, or (c) use more tolerant line processing like

```
timeInMyrs, moveFileName = line.rstrip().split(None, 1)
```

which is guaranteed not to return more than two pieces.

Comment: Thanks, the adjustment to the line processing worked!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for your problem is the the line.split() call is not resulting in the expected number of result substrings. Either the string you are splitting is the wrong string (bad input?) or there is a coding error...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
timeInMyrs, moveFileName = line.split()
```